# Possible to determine if a HDMI display connection is actively being used?

Tags: linux, hdmi, xorg

A computer with Kernel 6.2, an Intel IGP and an X11-based desktop is attached to a TV screen via HDMI. I'd like to determine if the TV is actively using the HDMI connection to the computer when it's tuned to that input.

Is there some sort of HDMI transfer status or similar that could be checked from the command line?
Or is the HDMI connection basically always on at its full transfer rate, even if the TV is used with its integrated satellite tuner?

Comment: What is the purpose of knowing this? Maybe you can use the `xrandr -q` command?

Comment: Unfortunately `xrandr - q` says 'connected' even when the TV is in standby mode. I'd like to check for activity (someone watches the HDMI input from the computer) in order to prevent an otherwise automated shutdown.

Comment: bump

My use case is to only pull images to my various screens from the doorbell camera IF any screen is actively on and set to the HDMI input connected to the little raspberry pi competitor boards (...supply issues, competitors are in stock).